# Does window.location.href takes away UI?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a problem when programming for apps.
I have a UI that displays but when I do a

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href="http://mywebsite.com";
</script>
```

after I have done it my UI disappears, does the code overlap the UI or what is happening? Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Sorry, was just tired, edited now :)

Comment: What does web have to do with programming an app in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

No overlapping or anything that sort.

It is being redirected to the new url provided.

When that code is executed, it is redirected to `http://mywebsite.com`

`window.location.href` contains the current url and when you overwrite it, it will redirect to the new url provided to it.

Comment: Is there anyway else to do this? relly need to display the website

Comment: @user3625881 for what kind of environment do you develop? Browser? Some mobile app framework?

Comment: @lethal-guitar It's an app, should work for both android and iOS, it goes into phonegap

Comment: @user3625881 then you need to look up how to "open a web page" with phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

In `window.location.href="http://mywebsite.com";` the browser navigates to the new URL supplied, i.e:`http://mywebsite.com`. that's why you may not be able to see your current UI.

for more reference see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)